# Force specific height of a table and add a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

So i have a empty table

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table border="1" id="committabelle"></table>
</div>
```

and a JScript function which fills the table

JSCRIPT:

```
function loadCommits(xml) { 
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table = '<tr><th>Commit</th><th>User</th><th>Datum</th><th>More Information</th></tr>';
    var shortId = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:ShortId");
    var user = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:UserId");
    var Date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a:Date");           
    for (i = 0; i < shortId.length; i++) {
        var tmp = shortId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue später an den Button
        var datetmp = Date[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue                
        var euro_date = datetmp.split('T');          
        var date_de = euro_date.join('--');
    table += "<tr><td>" +
        shortId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        user[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "</td><td>" +
        date_de +
        "</td><td>" +                
        '<button id="' + shortId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '" class="button button2" >Give me Information!</button>' +              
        "</td></tr>";                
    }.
    document.getElementById("committabelle").innerHTML = table;
}
```

The problem is that I can't change the size of the table. I wanted to change it so the height is for example 200px and then I used overflow so i get a scrollbar. I tried literally everything from height to max-height, table-layout: fixed and from overflow: auto to overflow: scroll. I event tried to force the size of the table with the browser-DOM-explorer after it is loaded in the browser.

I'm a little desperate right now. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: set parent height  https://jsfiddle.net/2dhvmsau/

Comment: @charlietfl Well, that works fine, but why :o?